# Rselenium error UnexpectedAlertOpen

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am new in Rselenium, I have been trying to scrape an X page, this page has a lot of pager page (1220), R clicks on each pager page and take information of each one with the following code:

```
links <- matrix(, 1220 = rpag, ncol = 1)
xx<-1
 for (y in 1:(1220)){
remDr$findElement(using="xpath", paste0("//*[@id='paginador_pagina_",y,"']/span"))$clickElement()
page_source<-remDr$getPageSource()
doc   <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
for(k in 1:32){ 
v <- paste0("//*[@id='rb_contResultados']/dl[",k,"]/div/a[2]")
link <- try(doc[v])
link<- try(toString(xmlAttrs(link[[1]])))
link<- sub(".*_blank, ", "", link)
links[xx,1] <- link
xx<- xx+1
 }
 Sys.sleep(runif(1, 3, 10))
 }
 remDr$closeWindow()
  } 
 }
```

But when R is in the page 166 (for example), I having the following error:

```
   Error:    Summary: UnexpectedAlertOpen
   Detail: A modal dialog was open, blocking this operation
   class: org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException
```

Why I'm having this error? How can I solve it?

Comment: In which line you are getting this error??